# Subject : 8 queens, when im printing out the board its giving me five copies and i want only one?

Tags: java

Output

```
Q   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   
    x   x   Q   x   x   x   x   

x   x   x   Q   x   x   x   x   
x   x   x   x   x   x   Q   x   
x   x   Q   x   x   x   x   x   
x   x   x   x   x   x   x   Q   
x   Q   x   x   x   x   x   x   
x   x   x   x   Q   x   x   x   
Q   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   
    x   x   x   x   Q   x   x   

x   x   x   Q   x   x   x   x   
x   Q   x   x   x   x   x   x   
x   x   x   x   x   x   Q   x   
x   x   Q   x   x   x   x   x   
x   x   x   x   x   Q   x   x   
x   x   x   x   x   x   x   Q   
x   x   x   x   Q   x   x   x   
Q   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   

x   x   x   x   Q   x   x   x   
x   Q   x   x   x   x   x   x   
x   x   x   Q   x   x   x   x   
x   x   x   x   x   x   Q   x   
x   x   Q   x   x   x   x   x   
x   x   x   x   x   x   x   Q   
x   x   x   x   x   Q   x   x   
Q   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   

x   x   Q   x   x   x   x   x   
x   x   x   x   Q   x   x   x   
x   Q   x   x   x   x   x   x   
x   x   x   x   x   x   x   Q   
x   x   x   x   x   Q   x   x   
x   x   x   Q   x   x   x   x   
x   x   x   x   x   x   Q   x   
Q   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   

x   x   Q   x   x   x   x   x   
x   x   x   x   x   Q   x   x   
x   x   x   Q   x   x   x   x   
x   Q   x   x   x   x   x   x   
x   x   x   x   x   x   x   Q   
x   x   x   x   Q   x   x   x   
x   x   x   x   x   x   Q   x   
Q   x   x   x   x   x   x   x
```

Code

```
public class ChessV2

{
    static String[][] board = new String[8][8];


   public static void main(String[] args)

   {

           for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
       {
                for(int j = 0; j < board.length; j++)
                {
                    board[i][j] = " ";
                }
       }

      placeQueens(0);    
    }


   public static boolean placeQueens(int column)

    {

        boolean placed = false;

        if(column == 8)
        {

            System.out.println();
            for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < board.length; j++)
                {
                    System.out.print(board[i][j] + "   ");
                }
                System.out.println();

            }
            placed = false; 
        }





        else
        {
          for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
          {
             if(!checkForQueens(i,column))
             {
                board[i][column] = "Q";

                if(placeQueens(column + 1) == true)
                {
                     placed = true;

                }

                else
                {
                    placed = false;
                   board[i][column] = "x";
                    }
             }
          }
        }

        return placed;
    }


   public static boolean checkForQueens(int row, int column)

    {
        boolean placeTaken = false;
        int newCol =0;
        int newRow;

        for(newRow = row - 1; newRow >= 0; newRow--) // vertically above the queen
        {

            if(board[newRow][column].equals("Q"))
                placeTaken = true;
        }

        for(newRow = row + 1; newRow < board.length; newRow++) // vertically under the queen
        {
            if(newRow >= 8 || column >= 8)
                break;

            if(board[newRow][column].equals("Q"))
                placeTaken = true;
        }

        for(newCol = column + 1; newCol < board.length -1; newCol++) // horizontally to the right of the queen
        {


            if(board[row][newCol].equals("Q"))
                placeTaken = true;
        }

         for(newCol = column - 1; newCol >= 0; newCol--) // horizontally to the left of the queen
        {


            if(board[row][newCol].equals("Q"))
                placeTaken = true;
        }

        newCol = column + 1;
        for(newRow = row - 1; newRow >= 0; newRow--) // Queen's upper right diagonal
        {
            if(newRow >= 8 || newCol >= 8)
                break;

            if(board[newRow][newCol].equals("Q"))
                placeTaken = true;

            newCol++;    
        }

        newCol = column + 1;
        for(newRow = row + 1; newRow < board.length - 1; newRow++) // Queen's lower right diagonal
        {
            if(newRow >= 8 || newCol >= 8)
                break;

            if(board[newRow][newCol].equals("Q"))
                placeTaken = true;

            newCol++;    
        }

        newCol = column - 1;
        for(newRow = row - 1; newRow >= 0; newRow--) // Queen's upper left diagonal
        {
            if(newRow < 0  || newCol < 0)   
                break;

            if(board[newRow][newCol].equals("Q"))
                placeTaken = true;

            newCol--;    
        }

        newCol = column - 1;
        for(newRow = row + 1; newRow < board.length; newRow++) // Queen's lower left diagonal
        {
            if(newRow < 0  || newCol < 0)
                break;

            if(board[newRow][newCol].equals("Q"))
                placeTaken = true;

            newCol--;    
        }

        return placeTaken;
    } 

   public static void print(String[][] array)
   {
       for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
       {
           for(int j = 0; j < array.length; j++)
           {
                    System.out.println(array[i][j] + "   ");
           }


       }
    }



}
```

Comment: While your output is helpful, we can't diagnose your code without seeing it.

Comment: What is it that you want us to do? Debug it for you!?

Comment: @sklitzz : if you can help please..

Comment: @WM,There is no code to understand and debug and how can one expect the solution

Comment: @Deepak Actually, there is code if you scroll down. But still, the question is poorly phrased so I voted to close.

Comment: @marcog,as you wish if you have voted to close the query,the choice is urs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's giving you five different solutions. If you only want one, then pass around a `boolean foundSolution` variable that you set to `true` once you've printed one and then check against this variable before printing subsequent solutions. Or better yet, check against it before continuing any further computation as once you've found one you don't need to continue any further.

EDIT: Actually, the output pasted in the question is incomplete. Full output is here: http://ideone.com/WeU4M which shows way temporary solutions. There are four copies of the full board at the end. If you follow what I suggested above you can prevent the duplicate copies printed at the end.